# How to use a virtual keyboard inside Libre Office Writier?

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice, keyboard-layout, google, internationalization

My current laptop has a standard (QWERTY) English-Hebrew keyboard that came with my Dell Latitude laptop; nothing is customized.

I need to use Thai letters in general and in a Libre Office Writer (LBW) document in particular.

### My problem

I thought to install a Google Virtual Keyboard but I am not sure output would automatically be inside a document edited with LBW.

### My question?

How to use a virtual keyboard inside Libre Office Writier?

That is to ask; [This Gmail solution seems nice](https://www.google.com/inputtools/services/features/virtual-keyboard.html) but how could I implement this or similar FOSS and Gratis solution (not necessarily by Google) in the OS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of virtual keyboards available. The popular choice is Onboard. You can install it by simply running:

```
sudo apt install onboard
```

After that you can start onboard app. You can customize it to your preferences. You can do some visual customizations from preferences tab in the tray and, if you want to do some drastic changes to tailor it to your needs, you can tweak the code. It is written in Python and licensed under GNU GPL v3. You can find the code here:
https://code.launchpad.net/onboard

[image]

Since Gnome 3.28, you can also launch new on-screen keyboard:
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-osk.html.en

To launch it, go to Settings => Universal Access => Typing => Screen Keyboard. Toggle it on and the keyboard will show when you click on any text area

Works just as fine:
[image]

Hope that helps!